# Show by induction that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $3^n \geq 1+2^n$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I started with the base case of P(1), which does work.

$3^1 = 3 \geq 1+2^1 = 3$

I then assumed P(k), which is

$3^k \geq 1+2^k$.

To prove P(k+1), which is $3^{k+1} \geq 1+2^{k+1}$, I have algebraically manipulated the following:

$3^{k+1} = 3 \cdot 3^k > 3^k \geq 1+2^k$

$2 \cdot 3^k \geq 2 + 2^{k+1}$

$2 \cdot 3^k - 1 \geq 1 + 2^{k+1}$.

At this juncture, I would obviously want to prove that $3^{k+1} > 2 \cdot 3^k - 1$. This is where I have run into trouble. If anyone could either help prove that, or show an alternate way of going about the problem, that would be fantastic.

Comment: You lost me here, specifically where the red starts: $3^{k+1} = 3 \cdot 3^k \color{red}{> 3^k \geq 1+2^k}$. Not because it is incorrect, but because it feels like you deviated from the natural solution. I recommend you use the induction hypothesis at this point: $3\cdot 3^{ k+1} \ge 3\cdot \left(1 + 2^k\right)$ and proceed from here.

Comment: Using the binomial theorem, $3^{n}=(1+2)^{n}\geq 1^{n}+2^{n}=1+2^{n}$ You can do induction on the middle inequality

Answer (score 2):

If $3^k\geqslant1+2^k$, then\begin{align}3^{k+1}&=3\times3^k\\&\geqslant3\times(1+2^k)\\&=3+3\times2^k\\&\geqslant1+2\times2^k\\&=1+2^{k+1}.\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

While I appreciate the terse symbolic proof above, I think this is the kind of problem that's amenable to a "softer" approach:

Notice that the left-hand side of the inequality grows by a factor of three every time $k$ increases by 1, while the right-hand side grows by less than a factor of two.  The result follows trivially.

Comment: Where José comes from, there's saying "throw sand on someone's eyes". That's what this intuitive approach does. It looks elegant, but when one tries to make it more formal, it becomes clear that the "terse symbolic" proof is clearer and shorter (and that's if yours won't just lead to the same proof). Plus, with this (apparently different) approach, you need to bake in induction in a sterile way, because the question requires induction. So it's not really helpful.

Comment: Why try to make it more formal in the first place, if it is obviously true?

Comment: Have you ever encountered anything that was obviously true that turned out to not be true? That's why.

Comment: Have you ever encountered something that was obviously true, that persisted being obviously true no matter how many times you poked at it?  A couple relevant links: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/
https://www.lesswrong.com/posts/X3HpE8tMXz4m4w6Rz/the-simple-truth